# If every bounded subset of a set $E$ of real numbers is countable, then $E$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to prove the following as review for an exam:

> If every bounded subset of a set $E\subseteq \Bbb R$ is countable, then $E$ is countable.

However, I am not sure how to approach this problem. Any hints?

Answer (score 7):

Write $E$ as the union of the subsets $[-n,n] \cap E$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Each $[-n,n] \cap E$ is a bounded subset of $E$, so it is countable. Then there is a general fact saying that if every set $U_n$ is countable ($n \in \mathbb{N})$, then $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$ is countable. So $E = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left( [-n,n] \cap E \right)$ is countable.

Comment: Clever. Thank you.

Comment: Try this one: Let $F$ be an uncountable subset of $\Bbb R.$ Let $x\in G$ iff (i) $x\in F,$ and (ii) for all $r>0$ both $(-r+x,x)\cap F$ and $(x,x+r)\cap F$ are uncountable. Prove that $G$ is uncountable and $F\setminus G$ is countable.